# AUTOSYS JOB DEPENDENCIES ON JOB STATUS ON_HOLD/ON_NOEXECUTION

Tags: shell, cron, job-scheduling, autosys, jil

I have the below job dependency -

BOX1 (Job_1,Job_2,Job_3)
BOX2 (Job_11,Job_12,Job_13)

job_3 should run when s(job_2) OR s(job_22)
Only one job should RUN job_2 OR job_22

I put Job_2 ON_HOLD and job_3 condition: s(job_2) OR s(job_22)
In this way job_3 is successful BUT BOX1 is always in RUNNING status due to ON_HOLD job.

I thought to use ON_NOEXEC instead of ON_HOLD on Job_2 but this always returns SUCCESS status for Job_2 and so Job_3 can run after Job_2 although job_22 is not successful.

So ON_HOLD is working good but it's not letting the BOX complete. How can I achieve the required result.

I tried ON_HOLD, it was working fine but BOX is not getting completed.
I tried ON_NOEXEC but this always produce SUCCESS for Job_2.

I want to handle the situation in JIL itself and no update later. If we keep job_2 ON_HOLD and Job_22 runs then the job should work. And if we keep job_22 ON_HOLD and Job_2 runs then also the flow should work fine.

Changing job status from outside is fine. No JIL update is expected after deployment.